# Mac System Services - application "(null)"

Tags: macos, cocoa, service

The problem is that I added my app to the system services and it was working fine, but, now, when I select the text, go to the Services menu and select my app the system says something like that:

"The service "xxx" could not be used because the application "(null)" is not compatible with the computer".

I have revised the code and everything seems to be ok, and in the bps results my app looks fine.

Any ideas of what can be happening?

Comment: I am seeing the same problem on an app I am working on. Were you able to resolve this issue later?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by doing the following:

Uninstall and remove all traces of the application in question.

Kill Launch Services: `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill`

and then:

When reinstalling the app, make sure it's being installed from a dmg. This is what caused the problem for me and a coworker....installing our app not from the dmg. Not sure why but this fixed it for us.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this after some serious head scratching today. Apparently the last part of your bundle identifier and the "Port Name" specified in your service settings in the `Info.plist` file have to match. Otherwise you get this weird error.

So basically, if you have the following bundle identifier:

```
com.yourcompany.yourapp
```

Your `NSPortName` should be `yourapp`. Otherwise you get the "application is not compatible" error.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true. I'm experiencing the same issue and this didn't solve it. Additionally, this has not been the case in my experience in the past.